# Can i created bak 2008 on sqlserver 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a database in sqlserver2012. I want created backup of it for use in sqlserver 2008.

It is possible to created Backup for use in sqlserver2008?

Comment: Erm, yes? Depends what the script is really, but it's quite likely that it **will** Where's the details!

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies in advance...I should have added this as a comment to one of the posts below.

If you are asking can you backup a SQL 2012 database and restore it to SQL 2008 (or any lower version for that matter), the answer is no.  Scripting is going to be the only way to do this. Bear in mind that not all functionality in 2012 is going to be available in lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

The Tasks/Generate Script/Advanced dialog contains a dropdown to select the target SQL Server version to script for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure you can, check this answer to know how to do it:

[Generate script in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429902/generate-script-in-sql-server-management-studio/9429970#9429970)