# Create a SQL script that pulls values from a table and puts them in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please read, my title is vague only because I can't explain what I need in a single sentence.

So I have a table `table1` and a `table2`. Now, `table1` contains data that I need to insert into `table2`. The issue is, `table1` does not exist in `environment 1`, but it does exist in `environment 2` (CPS and dev).

My question is; is there a way in SQL Management Studio to actually auto-generate a script that pulls the data from `table1`, and places them in a transaction that I can then run in our other environment? Such as:

```
UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 'data' etc...
```

Comment: `environment1 - environment1` are you referring to two different servers?

Comment: Are the tables are identical?

Comment: you may need to use linked server

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yes they are, however I cannot access them both at the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429902/generate-script-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: @RajKamuni Not possible in my situation.

Comment: So,please tell what is exactly mean by environment1,environment1 you are talking about

Comment: @RajKamuni Two different servers. Think dev and production. However, these envs don't share servers and I can't pull the data off one and onto another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link two servers first.

Please have a look [How to Create a Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx)

Then do something like below

```
Insert Into Server1.Databasename.dbo.TableName(Col1,Col2,Col3)
Select Col1, Col2, Col3
From Server2.Databasename.dbo.TableName
```

Other option is to create Simple ETL Package using SSIS to load data and insert.

Read more - [Creating a Simple ETL Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx)

Comment: Not possible, I should have made that more clear. I don't have control over something like that.

Comment: @TobyCaulk: Is this one off process or something you going to do regularly?

Comment: This is a one off process, we used a test table for canned data for a new feature but that table unfortunately does not exist in our pre-staging env so I have to manually copy the data over.

Comment: @TobyCaulk: Then the easiest option is to export the table in to an excel file and then import that file back to the other server where you can update the date!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create an SSIS package you could do it that way.

A DataFlow task with a database source and database destination. The database source will grab everything from table1 and insert it into the database destination which will be table 2.