# Visual Studio 2017 SQL database project

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, database-project

If I have visual sql database project, I want to drop all the objects in the database and create them again without dropping the actual DB. Is there a way to do that, if so how do I select this in the publish settings?

Answer (score 0):

Use generate script (SQL Server), it will generate a query for dropping and re creating the object on your database. here is another post,try to read it. Hope this helps.
[Generate script in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429902/generate-script-in-sql-server-management-studio)