# Suggestion in how to recopy entire database schema and data and not only data

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, schema

I have copied a database but I did not take precautions and copied only data, not the schema.

I realize this when by doing some validations the new database was accepting duplicates, and some keys were ignored.

Now I know that the solution to copy the database is to script the database schema and data using SSMS 
The procedure is:

> Right click on the database. Choose tasks. Then choose generate sql
>   scripts.

Now I am asking for some advice in how to rollback the situation and this time copy the data and schema of database. Is there a way to copy just the schema and apply the changes to data?

What approach would you recommend?

Comment: A better way is to take a backup and restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
Right click on the database. Choose tasks. Then choose generate sql scripts.
```

you can generate the schema of your database and same way with the data of your modified database. Then generate database and fill it using your generated SQL script.

[Create SQL script that create database and tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771047/create-sql-script-that-create-database-and-tables)