# How to copy structure of all tables to a new empty database?

Tags: sql-server

How do I copy the structure only (i.e., empty, no user data) of all tables, views, and indices from one SQL-Server database to new (empty) database?

(If anyone remembers ***dBase***, this was done with "copy struct" for each table.  I know also that this could be done by reverse-engineering the structure of the database into SQL statements using a tool like ***ERWin***, but I don't have that either.)

I'm working in a very bureaucratic (maybe even paranoid) client site, in which I can only create temp tables, and only read from the regular tables.  But it's really important that I be able to insert and update in a "safe" area.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: You could start with right-clicking the source database and choosing Tasks > Generate Scripts

Comment: [Create SQL script that create database and tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771047/create-sql-script-that-create-database-and-tables)

Comment: Again, thanks everyone for your answers and research :)  

(BTW I have done logical and physical data modeling, etc., using ERWIN and other tools.)

It's a new contract. Our client *won't allow us* use of many critical components. The client was dissatisfied with the previous contractor and reacted by clamping down extraordinary byzantine layers of control--and now we, the new people, are stuck with it.

The Point: I am not **ALLOWED** to do what you have suggest.  I've tried, and get "insufficient privileges."  

Our managers are "reaching out" to the client.

Thanks again.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 1):

You can generate scripts to generate a cloned test area for your database [Documenting and Scripting Databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191299%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSThomas Welcome to Stack Overflow. Correct Stack Overflow way to express "Thanks" is accepting an answer or voting, check http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's SQL Server supports this scenario through partially abstract tools that can work with the database model, visualize it, edit it, transfer the model from one place to another and even compute differences between models and this way create database schema upgrade script.

The part that I have memorized is that those models are stored in big XML files called `*.dacpac` and there is a schema compare button available if I open `*.sqlproj` project in Visual Studio

This is whole architectural concept, more abstract and different from `dBase`, and you can start learning more about it e.g. at

[Microsoft SQL Server - Data-tier applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546(v=sql.120).aspx)

(Or try Google: "**dacpac** deployment")