# how to export the schema of the database to export it to another server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, schema

I have a database with data, but I would like to export the schema of the data base to be able to create an empty data base.

I create the script, I select only tables and views, no users, because the idea it's install the data base in many computers with different users. The permissions I will manage individualy.

Well, in the next step, in advaned options, I select that I want triggers, foreign checks and all the other options and I create the script.

However I have some problems:

- When I delete my data base from the server and I use the script, I get the error that says that the data base does not exists. Is it possible in the script add the option to create the data base?
- If I create the data base manually, if I use the script I get an error that says that a column name is not valid.

At this point I was wondering where is the correct way to create a script of the schema to export it to another servers?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - `Object Explorer` window to script out the database and use `Object Explorer Details` window to script out tables (include triggers etc) and views. There are other 3rd party tools that can do a better job like Red-Gate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create SQL script that create database and tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771047/create-sql-script-that-create-database-and-tables)