# Is there any way to generate database scripts from a SQL query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I need to dump the database structure for a SQL Server database, but I need to do it from a SQL query or `sqlcmd` script.

Is there a valid way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You want to write a query that will script your entire database? Good luck with that. There are SO MANY things you need to script. It would take far less time and effort to create a backup and restore it.

Comment: Or do it from the GUI in SSMS. Notice how that is also fairly complex as far as options are concerned. If you really wanted to build something to mimic that you could use profiler to see what is being called but it won't be easy to replicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5771047/1260204. See also https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+schema+script+sql+server+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhmJ2juuXaAhULh-AKHTe9ARMQrQIoBDALegQIABBp&biw=2560&bih=1310

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the complete steps to generate script with data.

**1**
[image]

**2**
[image]

**3**

[image]

**4**

[image]

**5**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Open object explorer, right click db, tasks, generate scripts, next, script entire databse and all database objects, save to file, next, next, finish.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I’ve forgot to say that I need to do this from SQL query!

Comment: @FedericoAguirre When you finish, it scripts all the TSQL out to a file. Did you do the steps above?